# Getting 'signed out' after exactly 1 minute of inactivity

Tags: control-panel, php, session

I've launched a site recently which is being hosted on Vidahost's [Cloud servers](https://www.vidahost.com/page/cloud-hosting-feature-list). After exactly 1 minute of inactivity, anyone using the control panel is signed out. Except that if you refresh the page when you're "signed out", you're actually still signed in (but you lose any changes you were making).

So far I've tried changing the config setting `overridePhpSessionLocation` to auto, false and true, and nothing has changed. I've also tried changing the PHP version from 5.4 to 5.5 to no effect.

How can I stop this from happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was related to the place that the sessions were being stored with my hosting company (Vidahost). Using the Utils section in Craft2, we managed to track it down to being stored with memcache. This meant that `true` and `auto` wouldn't work, and we had to set the override to `false`. False is meant to be the default anyway, but it seems to be working now that it's hardcoded.

The key lines to look for when debugging this are:

```
session.save_handler    memcache
session.save_path       tcp://10.168.1.55:11211?persistent=0&amp;weight=1&amp;timeout=5&amp;retry_interval=15`
```